# Why my Nokogiri selector not working?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

This is my first attempt using Nokogiri, but it doesn't work and I don't understand why:

This is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
   <book id="bk101">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>44.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <description>An in-depth look at creating applications
      with XML.</description>
   </book>
</catalog>
```

I'm using this code:

```
require 'nokogiri'

f = File.open("test.xml")
doc = Nokogiri::XML(f)
nodes = doc.xpath("title")
nodes.each do |node|
    print node.text
end
```

I am getting the nodes as a nil class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select nodes matching the selector try:

```
nodes = doc.xpath("//title")
```

Comment: ty now it works. What does then .xpath("title") mean.

Comment: Well in that way I think you just select something in the root.

Answer (score 0):

I'd write the code like:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(File.read("test.xml"))
nodes = doc.search("title")
puts nodes.map(&:text)
```

Back to the problem. You used:

```
nodes = doc.xpath("title")
```

which is forcing Nokogiri to interpret your selector as XPath, and will look for an immediate ancestor of `<catalog>` named `<title>`. That doesn't exist. Instead, you'd need to use `//title` if you want to search throughout the document for any `<title>` tags.

Or, instead of forcing `xpath`, if you'd used `search` instead, Nokogiri would have decided you meant it to use a CSS selector `title`, and it would have worked correctly, since, in CSS, `title` would search the entire document.

I recommend using CSS over XPath as it's more readable. XPath is extremely powerful but it also quickly gathers a lot of visual noise as the selector becomes more powerful.